# Filtering Haystack results

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am trying to build a full text search for Recipes. I have specified the ingredient as the document field. Everything is working fine but i also want to put on some more constraints to the Search Results.

For example i want to perform a full text search on field ingredients but want the models to be searched only those matching the category specified.

I looked through the docs and was not able to find any Query parameters that would need to be set nor I found any changes I have to do to the Index.

I am using elasticsearch in the backed for Indexing, if that matters.

```
class ArticleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex,indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True,model_attr='ingredients')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    category = indexes.CharField(model_attr='category')
    image_link = indexes.CharField(model_attr='image_link')
    publication_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publication_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Article
```

Comment: can you provide the view that handles the search requests? I can't see why you can't just narrow your `SearchQuerySet` down like this: `sqs.filter(category__exact=self.cleaned_data['user_provided_category])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to narrow the search results down you just have to use a custom form to get the additional filter information from the user and use that input in your view to narrow the `SearchQuerySet` down.

It could look like this:

```
from django import forms
from haystack.forms import SearchForm
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView


class MySearchForm(SearchForm):
    category = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def search():
        sqs = super(MySearchForm, self).search()

        category = self.cleaned_data.get('category')

        if category:
            sqs = sqs.filter(category__exact=category)

        return sqs


class MySearchView(SearchView):
    form_class = MySearchForm
```

It's just a minimal example and i didn't test the code but it should look about like this. You could also use a `Select` or `MultipleSelect` in your custom form to let the user only choose form predefined categories.